# Deployment CORS issue with Heroku on backend and Vercel on front

Tags: database, heroku, heroku-postgres, vercel

I am having some issues deploying my full stack capstone. I have both ends deployed to Vercel and Heroku respectively.I did not have any issues when running it locally. When I register a user deployed, it does POST and create that user to the db, but when I go to log in with that user I get the following CORS error:

Access to fetch at 'https://desolate-reaches-15214.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login' from origin 'https://mind-your-fitness.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
auth-api-service.js:48 POST https://desolate-reaches-15214.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login net::ERR_FAILED

Here is my App.js from the backend. I am not sure what else you guys might need to help:

```
    require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const { CLIENT_ORIGIN } = require("./config");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const { NODE_ENV } = require("./config");
const workoutsRouter = require("./workouts/workouts-router");
const usersRouter = require("./users/users-router");
const authRouter = require("./authentication/auth-router");

const app = express();

const morganOption = NODE_ENV === "production" ? "tiny" : "common";
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan(morganOption));
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());

app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/api/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/api/workouts", workoutsRouter);

app.use(function errorHandler(error, req, res, next) {
  let response;
  if (NODE_ENV === "production") {
    response = { error: { message: "server error" } };
  } else {
    console.error(error);
    response = { message: error.message, error };
  }
  res.status(500).json(response);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Any solution? I am also looking for the fix.

Comment: Hi @Shadab Yes I did actually. After 2 full days, I finally  figured it out. Of course it was something very simple.

For anyone that may come across this issue in the future, it ended up not actually being a CORS error at all. That was just the error the browser was throwing back in the network tab when it would time out after 30 seconds.

It ultimately ended up being that I didn't have my JWT_SECRET in the config var on Heroku. It wasn't pulling it from my .env because obviously, my .env was local. So yes, lesson learned there. Hopefully this helps you as well!